# Python, check if a number is in a range of many ranges in a list.

Tags: python, list, search

If there are integer lists like these:

```
a_list = [2501, 2783, 3088, 3980, 465, 1001, 39392911, 39394382, 488955,489087, ......]
b_list = [474, 498, 47478821, 47479800, 3774, 8970, 484000, 486000......]
```

every 2 numbers indicate a range of natural numbers, for example, the ranges of **a_list** would be:

```
2501     2783      # 2501，2502，2503，2504，2505，2506,......,2783
3088     3980 
465      1001 
39392911 39394382 
488955   489087
......
```

For a given number, search for the range where it belongs to, and with priority of a_list > b_list i.e. if a range is found in a_list, stop searching and move on to the next number for searching.

I had test run for searching around 50 numbers which took about 7 minutes. I have a big dataset which could be 20 million numbers need to be searched in his way.

**How to code this to do it faster?**

============= more conditions and information =============

- could be more than 10 thousand numbers in each list.
- could be up to 30 million numbers for searching.
- the size of list is always n * 2
- a_list: [1st < 2nd, 3rd < 4th, ......]
- the numbers in the lists might occur more than once.
- the priority: a_list > b_list.

I have code as following:

```
hasFound = 0

if hasFound == 0:
    for x, y in izip(*[iter(a_list)]*2):   # gives every 2 numbers
        if aNumber in range(x,y):
            a_list_counter +=1 
            hasFound = 1
            break

if hasFound == 0:       
    for x, y in izip(*[iter(b_list)]*2):
        if aNumber in range(x,y):
            b_list_counter += 1
            hasFound = 1
            break
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a brute force method. There's a more elegant method you're not thinking of.

Comment: `if aNumber in range(x,y) ` should be just `x <= aNumber <= y`

Comment: @Nsh It's worth noting that the reason for that is that `range(x, y)` in Python 2.x actually builds a list of all the numbers, which takes time and memory. In Python 3.x, `range()` returns a special object that can do things like this efficiently.

Comment: @Almo, You right, i was trying to do it better, but couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Nsh, I changed this as suggested, it worked faster than my original code, but still slow. Thanks.

Comment: @Almo, do you have any good suggestion or hint about the elegant method?

Comment: Apologies, I think I misunderstood the problem, and will have to think about this some more.

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but my intuition says that you want to do a processing pass on the lists first and reduce them to the smallest possible set of ranges. Like (1, 5) (3, 6) would be come (1, 6).

Comment: @Almo, I thought about this, but haven't got a good algorithm for it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toss them all in one big dictionary:

```
a_list = [2501, 2783, 3088, 3980, 465, 1001, 39392911, 39394382, 488955,489087, ......]
b_list = [474, 498, 47478821, 47479800, 3774, 8970, 484000, 486000......]
# into
ranges = {'a': [2501, 2783, 3088, 3980, 465, 1001, 39392911, 39394382, 488955,489087, ......],
          'b': [474, 498, 47478821, 47479800, 3774, 8970, 484000, 486000......]}
```

Then go through each list in order, mostly the way you were doing it before:

```
numbers = [list of your target numbers]
scores = {} # dict to store results in

for number in numbers:

    for range_name in sorted(ranges):
        range_list = ranges[range_name]
        groups = zip(*[iter(range_list)] * 2)
        if any(start <= number < end for start,end in groups):
            scores.setdefault(range_name, 0) += 1
```

Alternatively (and I'm not sure if this is faster or not) you could do:

```
for number in numbers:
    for range_name in sorted(ranges):
        range = ranges[range_name]
        if sorted(range + [number]).index(number) % 2:
            scores.setdefault(range, 0) += 1
```

In this case you're throwing a new number into a sorted list, re-sorting it (which is fast using TimSort), and seeing if it falls between two existing numbers.

Comment: this part: `scores.setdefault(range_name, 0) += 1` gives error:  SyntaxError: can't assign to function call, would defaultdict(list) do? I didn't get meaning of += 1. And the `sorted(ranges)` because searching based on priority, right?

Comment: Are you using `scores = {}` or is scores a defaultdict? No `defaultdict(list)` won't work since we're not building lists....

Comment: hi, i fixed the error, i used scores as dict. I tested your 2 methods with 1000, 10000 numbers, and prints the microseconds, my code is slightly faster than your 1st method, and much faster than the 2nd method. But, thanks for the helps you provide.

Comment: @Xiangwu "I used scores as dict" isn't that exactly my first method? Yeah it doesn't surprise me terribly that the second method is much slower -- `list.index` is fairly slow.

Comment: sorry that I might have confused you. for the 2 methods in your answer, i have tried both. got the error with the 1st method. "I used scores as dict" was just to answer your last question. Now, I am think if I can do this in parallel/multiprocessing.